# limit the word count and add a read more link

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok i have this code so far which is in my wordpress template so precisely this a wordpress stuff.

```
<?php

    $post_id = 266;
    echo "<div id='widgets-wrapper3'><div id='marginwidgets' style='overflow: auto; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border: none !important;'>";

    $queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
    echo "<div class='thewidgets'>";
    echo $queried_post->post_content;
    echo '</div>';

    echo "</div></div>";    
?>
```

as you can see into the code, the routine is, to display the post which has an id of 266, now all i want is to limit the word count in the post content of that post, let say I want to limit the word to 300 and then add a read more link. how to make that please?

hope there's someone here who figured out how to make that.

I am open in, Ideas, recommendation and suggestion. Hope someone here could help, thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: This functionality is actually built into Wordpress. http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: @RickCalder: yes i know, but i just dont know how to integrate it into my current code or to add that function into my current code

Comment: @Kolink: those code above is currently I tried.

Comment: None of the code above looks even vaguely like an attempt to limit the word count.

Comment: @Kolink: I replace this line echo `$queried_post->post_content;` to `echo substr($queried_post->post_content, 0, 300);` from Nwafor below. It works good but certainly the image in the post is included into the word count.

Comment: how to not to include the image into the word count limit?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

or use php substr:

```
echo get_sub($queried_post->post_content, 300);


function get_sub($str, $max=300)
{
$ar = explode($str);
$count = 0;
$new_str = "";
$del = " ";
foreach($ar as $a)
{
    if($count == 0)
    {
        //no space
        $del = "";
    }

    if($count < $max)
    {
        $new_str .= $del.$a;
    }
    $count++;
}
return $new_str;
}
```

if the content contains html elements, its a problem.
hope it helps

Comment: 300 characters does not equal 300 words.

Comment: @Kolink: so I should make it like, I will limit only the content that has been wrap by a p tag with a class or by a class?

Comment: this work, but if I have an image into the post, it is included into the limitation

Comment: I use your code substr($queried_post->post_content, 0, 300); and it works ok, but the image is include into the word coutn limit. how to make it like any image into the post content should not be included into the word count limit .